# How to show another user the goals I completed?

Tags: views, 7

I have a view that shows the goals (created using the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module) I've completed. For this I use the view that comes with the Goals module (and which only shows the Goals completed by the current user).

But I'd like that other users could see that view too whenever other users browse my account. So that another user can see which goals I completed (instead of showing the goals completed by that other user).

So I'm looking for help about:

- placing the view.
- making it visible to other users whenever they browse my profile.

Comment: So what exactly is what you need help in? Placing the view in your user page (ex: /user/1)? or is the view in your user page already but others are not able to see it?

Comment: Placing the view and make it visible to other users whenever they see my profile

Answer (score 1):

Here is an export of a view, which is an improved version of the view that is included with the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module (disclosure: I'm its maintainer):

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'goals_completed_by_a_user';
$view->description = 'A block showing goals completed by a user.';
$view->tag = 'Goals';
$view->base_table = 'goals';
$view->human_name = 'Goals Completed by User';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Your completed goals';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'grid';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Goal: Goal - completed by users */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['goals_completed_goals']['id'] = 'goals_completed_goals';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['goals_completed_goals']['table'] = 'goals';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['goals_completed_goals']['field'] = 'goals_completed_goals';
/* Field: Goal: URL */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['url']['id'] = 'url';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['url']['table'] = 'views_entity_goal';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['url']['field'] = 'url';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['url']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['url']['link_to_entity'] = 0;
/* Field: Goal: Goal Image */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['id'] = 'goal_img';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['table'] = 'field_data_goal_img';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['field'] = 'goal_img';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => 'goal_image',
  'image_link' => '',
);
/* Field: Goal: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'goals';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['text'] = '[title][goal_img]<br/>';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['path'] = '[url]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Goal - completed by users: Created */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'goals_completed_goals';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['relationship'] = 'goals_completed_goals';
/* Contextual filter: Goal - completed by users: User */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['table'] = 'goals_completed_goals';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['relationship'] = 'goals_completed_goals';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_type'] = 'current_user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';

/* Display: My goals */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'My goals', 'block');
$handler->display->display_options['display_description'] = 'Goals completed by the current user';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;

/* Display: User's Goals */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'User\'s Goals', 'block_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['title'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Goals completed user';
$handler->display->display_options['display_description'] = 'Goals completed by a selected user';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'goal_img' => 'goal_img',
  'title' => 'title',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'goal_img' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'title' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Goal: URL */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['url']['id'] = 'url';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['url']['table'] = 'views_entity_goal';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['url']['field'] = 'url';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['url']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['url']['link_to_entity'] = 0;
/* Field: Goal: Goal Image */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['id'] = 'goal_img';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['table'] = 'field_data_goal_img';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['field'] = 'goal_img';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['goal_img']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => 'goal_image',
  'image_link' => '',
);
/* Field: Goal: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'goals';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['text'] = '[title][goal_img]<br/>';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['path'] = '[url]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Goal - completed by users: User */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['table'] = 'goals_completed_goals';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['relationship'] = 'goals_completed_goals';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_type'] = 'raw';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_options']['index'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
```

In this view I've added an extra block named "User's Goals". This extra block has a contextual filter which I configured like so:

- When the filter value is not available: Provide a default value with Type = "Provide raw value from URL" and Path component = "2" (this is what differs from the Views block delivered with the Goals module).
- In the block settings I've adapted the block visibility to only show this block on pages with a path that matches `user/*` ( i.e. when browsing a user's account, as in your question). And of course I've then enabled this extra block also to display it in an appropriate theme region.

**Note**: I've also extended the list of fields shown in the block, by also adding the Goal URL (excluded from display) and Goal title, though that is not really relevant to answer the question here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a [block display](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/views-block.html) for your view.
2. [Place the block](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/block/overview) on your user page in whatever region you want.
3. Ensure it is accessible to all authenticated users.